# Get list of table names in oracle from information schema

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, rdbms

I am using the following query in MySQL and POSTGRESQL.

**MySQL**
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='SmartHome' and table_name like '%House%'

**POSTGRESQL**.
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='public' and table_name like '%House%'.

I want to know equivalent query in **Oracle DB**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below sql queries for the same -

```
select * from user_tables; /* The relational tables owned by the current user.*/

select * from dba_tables;  /* describes all relational tables in the database - For this you need to login as a DBA */

select * from tab; /* Gives you all tables */

select * from cat; /* Gives you sequences as well */
```

Comment: How can i get list of tables associated with particular database, is this query right?    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES  WHERE OWNER='DBName' and TABLE_NAME like '%HOUSE%'

Comment: It should work just fine, just add a litle tweak if you don't want to miss any lower case tables - SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER='DBName' and upper(TABLE_NAME) like '%HOUSE%'

Comment: If the same solves your concern, please Accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks and sure buddy

Answer (score 0):

select TABLE_NAME from user_tables